# Pointer to an integer array

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose `mat` is a pointer to an array of size `5` where each element is an integer

```
int (*mat)[5];
```

and I have initialized it as

```
int a[5] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
mat = &a;
```

I've written the code as

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int (*mat)[5];
    int a[5] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    mat = &a;
    printf("%p\n%p\n%d\n", mat, *mat, **mat);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
43800  
43800  
5
```

Why does `mat` and `*mat` give the same answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: @JGroven Array decaying means that, when an array is passed as a parameter to a function, it's treated identically to ("decays to") a pointer. However, there is no any passing case ??

Comment: @snr I was under the impression that array decaying is the implicit conversion from array to pointer, and that using an array as a parameter is merely a demonstration of decay.

Comment: @JGroven ((: just was kidding, Thank you for explanation freshman

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in nearly every case. The two exceptions are the `sizeof` and the `&` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture may help:

```
     +---+            +---+
mat: |   | ------> a: | 5 | a[0]
     +---+            +---+
                      | 4 | a[1]
                      +---+
                       ...
                      +---+
                      | 1 | a[4]
                      +---+
```

So, first thing we notice - the address of the *array* `a` is the same as the address of the *array element* `a[0]`.  The *expression* `a` has type "5-element array of `int`"; unless that expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted ("decays") to an expression of type "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the address of the first element of the array.  Thus, the *expressions* `&a`, `a`, and `&a[0]` will all yield the same *value* (address of the first element of `a`), even though they're not all the same *type* (`int (*)[5]`, `int *`, `int *`).

So, given the above, all of the following are true:

```
  mat == &a 
 *mat ==  a
**mat ==  a[0]
```

Since `&a` and `a` evaluate to the same address, `mat` and `*mat` evaluate to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, the address of an array is the same as its first element's. In this context, `*mat` is of type `int[5]` which decays to `int *`, i.e. a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: if I have an array int a[5], a is an integer pointer containing &a[0],but what is the address of a?

Comment: @metasj `&a` and `&a[0]` have a different type. `a` is of type `int[5]`. `&a[0]` is of type `int *`. `&a` is of type `int (*)[10]`. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @metasj `a` is not an integer pointer but it will evaluate as an integer pointer in most kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 0):

`mat` is a [pointer to array 5 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*mat%29%5B5%5D%3B).

`*mat` is an *array 5 of int*.

Arrays such as `*mat`, when pass to functions are converted in "... to an expression with type *pointer to type* that points to the initial element of
the array object...". C11 §6.3.2.1 3

`*mat` in `printf("%p\n",*mat);` is a *pointer to an `int`*.

---

> "Why does `mat` and `*mat` give the same answer?"

These both point to the same memory location. `mat` points to the array.  In `printf()`, `*mat` points to the first array element, an `int`.

As pointers, `mat` and `*mat` point to very different types.  They *could* have employed different presentation (even size) and yielded different *text* output, yet their *values* are equivalent.  This difference is uncommon.

---

Further, `"%p"` expects a `void*`.  Use a `void*` cast for portable code.

```
printf("%p\n%p\n",mat,*mat);  // undefined behavior
printf("%p\n%p\n",(void*) mat,(void*) *mat);
```